# Giving multiple classes in a single library the same name

Tags: naming, coding-standards

The project that raised this question is in C#, but it could apply to most languages that use namespaces.

I've read many things on good naming practices:

- "Don't prefix your class names with their namespace name. That's just creating unnecessary duplication." (Smurf naming)
- "One of the uses for namespaces is separating code and name collisions. Use them that way."
- "When I'm reading code from a project and come across a class name, I want to know exactly which class is being referenced and not have to check which namespaces have been imported."

What I haven't been able to figure out is the best way to name classes in namespaces that perform similar tasks, but are completely independent from each other.

For example, let's say I have an audio codec library. The code in each codec namespace is not dependent on the others, but they all depend on a namespace containing common, generic code.

I might have classes like these. (Don't read too much into the names, they're only examples.)

Vorbis codec:

```
Project.Vorbis.VorbisEncoder
Project.Vorbis.VorbisDecoder
Project.Vorbis.VorbisFrame
Project.Vorbis.VorbisChannel
Project.Vorbis.VorbisParameters
```

ATRAC3+ codec:

```
Project.Atrac3P.Atrac3PEncoder
Project.Atrac3P.Atrac3PDecoder
Project.Atrac3P.Atrac3PFrame
Project.Atrac3P.Atrac3PChannel
Project.Atrac3P.Atrac3PParameters
```

IMA ADPCM codec:

```
Project.ImaAdpcm.ImaAdpcmEncoder
Project.ImaAdpcm.ImaAdpcmDecoder
Project.ImaAdpcm.ImaAdpcmFrame
Project.ImaAdpcm.ImaAdpcmChannel
Project.ImaAdpcm.ImaAdpcmParameters
```

Is this good design, or is it too repetitive? I don't like repeating the namespace name in the class name, but I don't know if that's preferable to duplicating class names like this:

```
Project.Vorbis.Encoder
Project.Atrac3P.Encoder
Project.ImaAdpcm.Encoder
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As usual, that depends. It depends on the places where the unprefixed class names can be used. [Disclaimer: I'm a Java freak, but I think my experience will be applicable to C# as well.]

My rule of thumb is that symbols that are visible outside of their home namespace should have a unique name over all namespaces of the project.

If references to some `Encoder` will only show up in classes from the the same namespace, then, as a reader of the code, I'd expect the `Encoder` name to stand for the local one. In Java, I'd give the `Encoder` class a package-local visibility.

But if the `Encoders` are visible outside of their home namespace, I'd go for the long names.

E.g. Java has a negative example with the classes `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date`, which sometimes I had to use in the same method (bridging between core algorithm and database) - that forced me to use fully-qualified classnames at least for one of them :-(.

Comment: A unique name over all namespaces?  Eeek!  Not I - to each their own though, I suppose. (I thought namespaces were specifically to have to avoid doing that late 90s crap)

Comment: Of course, that's what namespaces are for. But what I try to avoid is e.g. having 5 different classes of the same name and usage all over the project, so I either have to prefix their usage with the namespace or I have to guess (look at the imports) which class it is.

Comment: As someone who programs in both Java and C#, I can see the advantage of this, but it would get quite unmanageable after a while.  The namespaces have to be distinct between one another and the classes within a given namespace must be distinct from one another.  Anything else goes I think.

Comment: This ONLY applies to Java because Java either allows you to import a specific symbol (which then must have a locally unique name), or you must use the fully qualified name. So you get `VorbisEncoder` with `import com.example.myapp.vorbis.VorbisEncoder` or you have to spell out `com.example.myapp.vorbis.Encoder` each and every time. In languages with type aliases this does not apply.

Answer (score 3):

Organization of a project can be somewhat subjective, but:

```
Namespace
Project.Codec
```

Maybe create a folder under codec called \Encoding

Classes and interfaces under \Encoding

```
IEncoder
VorbisEncoder : IEncoder
Atrac3Encoder : IEncoder
```

...And so forth.  The sub folder is optional but if you have a lot of implementations of encoders, decoders, etc. it could be useful as a further organizational level for the project.

Finally, to import:

```
using Project.Codec.Encoding;
```

This would give you access to all the encoders.

Comment: In this particular example, each codec has a different API due to the differences in the audio formats. There _is_ a set of classes that implement a common interface, as you described, to provide a "higher-level" API for each codec.